# Using Init method without passing a parameter?

Tags: swift, swiftui, syntactic-sugar

I have an array of CLPlacemark. I'm following and example and I don't understand why the second code is correct.

Example 1: This code is correct.

```
let placemarks: [CLPlacemark]
....

placemarks
.compactMap({ placemark in
      Location(placemark: placemark)
})

...
```

Example 2: This code is also correct.

```
let placemarks: [CLPlacemark]
....

placemarks
.compactMap(Location.init(placemark:))

...
```

Do you know why I can create Locations without passing the parameter?

Comment: When the parameter in exactly matches the parameter type of the method you call then the compiler can infer the parameter and you don't need to explicitly write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialisers can be thought of as a regular function that returns a value of whatever type the initialiser is initialising. They have a type when you explicitly write out `init`.

In the same way that you can write:

```
func makeLocation(placemark: CLPlacemark) -> Location? { ... }
// I'm not *calling* `makeLocation` here - I'm just assigning the function itself to f
let f: (CLPlacemark) -> Location? = makeLocation(placemark:) // or just makeLocation
```

You can also write:

```
struct Location {
    init?(placemark: CLPlacemark) { ... }
}
let f: (CLPlacemark) -> Location? = Location.init(placemark:) // or just Location.init
```

See also [this section of the Swift Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/functions/#Using-Function-Types) if this is the first time you have seen a function itself being used as a *value*, instead of being invoked.

It works the same way in `compactMap`. `compactMap` expects a function of type `(T) -> U?` where `T` and `U` are type parameters.

You could pass the lambda `{ placemark in Location(placemark: placemark) }`. This lambda would be of type `(CLPlacemark) -> Location?`. But the type of `Location.init` is also `(CLPlacemark) -> Location?` matches this pattern, so you are able to pass it to `compactMap` too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get it now.